# Total Commander and DropBox

Tags: dropbox, total-commander

I already have Total Commander in my DropBox directory, and I have set it to have its .INI field in the program directory.
That should be enough, right?

I am remote desktopping, and both the PCs have different button bars, hot lists for quick directory change (Ctrl-D), etc.

Obviously I am missing something, but what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in wincmd.ini you see hardcoded paths to the exact location of e.g. the "Buttonbar" , so the dropbox location should be the same on both PCs.